# "Отношения разрушают не расстояния, а сомнения" - нет ли тут смысловой ошибки?

Tags: смысл

"Отношения разрушают не расстояния, а сомнения" - была приведена цитата на каком-то форуме. Речь идёт об отношениях полов, и, если следовать по ходу предложения, то вроде как получается, что сомнения были разрушены не расстояниями, а отношениями. А не правильнее ли сказать "Не расстояния, а сомнения разрушают отношения"?

Answer (score 3):

Правильнее, но в данном предложении применена инверсия, автор имел право, инверсия всегда выразительнее.Логическое ударение на дополнении "отношения". Смысл Вы поняли верно, другие тоже истолкуют так, потому что иначе получится ерунда, алогизм. Вот если истолковать можно и так, и так, то не рекомендуется применять инверсию, потому что норма - прямой порядок слов и на 1 месте должен стоять состав подлежащего.